# Issue with video playback and interstitial ad in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, exoplayer2.x, applovin

#### MAX Plugin Version

2.5.0

#### Flutter Version

3.10.2

#### Device/Platform Info

Poco X3 Pro Android 13 and Also other devices.

#### Current Behavior

I encountered an issue where my app crashes when trying to load an ad while playing a video using the `video_player` package. The ads load successfully on other screens, but this issue occurs specifically when attempting to play a video and show the interstitial ad.

Interestingly, I don't encounter this issue in debug mode, only in release mode.

Packages used in my app:

- video_player: ^2.6.1
- applovin_max: ^2.5.0
- flutter_local_notifications: ^14.1.0
- onesignal_flutter: ^3.5.1

Error Logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-16-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): Process: com.videodownloader.udownload, PID: 30065
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: k9.w3
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k9.n.o(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at ua.a.b(Unknown Source:40)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at pa.y.c(Unknown Source:21)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at pa.y.a(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.T0(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.c0(Unknown Source:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.M0(Unknown Source:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.Q(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.u0.apply(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.d2.accept(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.d2.accept(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.d2.accept(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.a.forEachRemaining(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.f0(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.I0(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.U.y(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.L0(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.k2.forEach(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.g2.accept(Unknown Source:24)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.Y.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source:20)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.f0(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.I0(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.U.y(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.c.L0(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at j$.util.stream.k2.forEachOrdered(SourceFile:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.m0(Unknown Source:70)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at qa.e1.r(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k1.a.g(Unknown Source:26)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at i1.b$a.run(Unknown Source:210)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k9.n.m(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k9.n.l(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at ua.a.b(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        ... 30 more
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create VMBridge instance
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k9.w3.d(Unknown Source:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        at k9.w3.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(30065):        ... 33 more
```

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

#### Expected Behavior

*No response*

#### How to Reproduce

To reproduce the issue:

1. Ensure you have the latest versions of the `video_player` and `applovin_max` packages in your Flutter app.

   - video_player: ^2.6.1
   - applovin_max: ^2.5.0
2. Create a screen in your app where you have both the video player and the ad.
3. Play a video using the `video_player` package.
4. Attempt to load an ad using the AppLovin SDK after the video starts playing.
5. Observe that the app crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-16-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): Process: com.videodownloader.udownload, PID: 30065
E/AndroidRuntime(30065): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: k9.w3
...
```

Please note that this issue occurs specifically on Android and is not reproducible in debug mode but only in release mode.

It's important to mention that this issue is observed when trying to load the ad after playing a video using the `video_player` package. Ads load successfully on other screens, indicating that the issue is specific to the combination of video playback and ad loading.

By following the steps above, developers should be able to understand and reproduce the issue in order to investigate and resolve it effectively.

#### Additional Info

*No response*